# Fetching and inserting date with time stamp

Tags: sql, perl

I am writing a perl script which copies data from a table in one db to the same table in other DB. I am using DBI to obtain connection to DBS.
I noticed that when I am copying data,it's not copied properly.
In source table if date is like this-'04/22/1996 13:51:15 PM'
In destination table it's appearing like this-'22 APR 1996'.
Can anyone help me in copying exact date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: 04/22/1996 is basically the same date as 22 APR 1996, only in different format. Use the appropriate date formatting functions provided by your database system.

Comment: if both are date field columns then it sounds like a formatting issue on presenting the date, maybe your two systems dont have the same format for dates by default.

Comment: Yes . Both are date fields. I am selecting data using select query and then store the entire data in an array . And the for each roe in the array I am  calling a insert statement which will take data from the array and inserts to the table. Can anyone tell me How can I mention the format and where can I do that.

Comment: Tell us which databases you are using. Are they both the same? Show us the code you are using to transfer the data and the code you're using to display this difference. Are the dates stored in datetime columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $datetimestr = '04/22/1996 13:51:15 PM';
# 1) parse datetime
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern=>'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p', 
    on_error  => 'croak',
);
my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime($datetimestr,);
# 2) format datetime for your database format
warn $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: One comment on date time, it's relatively slow if you're calling it a bunch. If speed is an issue writing your own parser is possibly worth it, especially if you don't need timezone or day of week information.

Comment: DateTime really slow, but if we are working with the database, it is not so expensive. You can write fast parser for a specific format, but to maintain this code will be difficult.